# Application Installation in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I needed to know that when my a application installs in a device in android, which component of application framework decides its installation site and how i can manages its installation site (mobile memory or SD card)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide option for your installation on your SD card.You will need this in your manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"
```

You can choose among these.
But by default your app will always be saved on device.The user can always transfer it to SD card .

Answer (score 1):

check the android documentation here[1]. To install to SD Card put

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

in your manifest.

For backwards compatibility use "auto" instead of "preferExternal".

[1] http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file, it is set as default so when the user downloads the application, it is downloading into their mobile memory. If you want the user to have to option of moving the application to their SD card, you can add:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

It should be placed into the manifest section. For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.application"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```